# Functions "filter" and "filter-out" do not remove newlines

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

***From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#Text-Functions):***

> `$(filter PATTERN...,TEXT)`
>   
>   
>   Returns all whitespace-separated words in TEXT that *do* match any
>   of the PATTERN words, removing any words that *do not* match.  The
>   patterns are written using `%`, just like the patterns used in the
>   `patsubst` function above.
>
> ---
>
> `$(filter-out PATTERN...,TEXT)`
>   
>   
>   Returns all whitespace-separated words in TEXT that *do not* match
>   any of the PATTERN words, removing the words that *do* match one or
>   more.  This is the exact opposite of the `filter` function.

What does "***whitespace*** - separated words" mean?

Well, we think we know. At-least, when assuming a "normal" locale.

So, for a *"C" ("POSIX")* locale [we have](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html):

> #### "space"
>
> ---
>
> Define characters to be classified as white-space characters.
>   
>   
>   In the POSIX locale, at a minimum, the `<space>`, `<form-feed>`, `<newline>`, `<carriage-return>`, `<tab>`, and `<vertical-tab>` shall be included.

***Now, a makefile, like this:***

```make
define foo
a
b
endef


all :
    echo '$(filter a b,$(foo))'
```

***Running, I get:***

```console
echo ''
```

***Let's try the `filter-out` case:***

```make
define foo
a
b
endef


all :
    -echo '$(filter-out a b,$(foo))'
```

***Running, I get:***

```console
echo 'a
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
makefile:8: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: [all] Error 2 (ignored)
b'
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
makefile:8: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: [all] Error 2 (ignored)
```

So, clearly Make does not handle here properly a legitimate `white-space` (newline).

Right?

Answer (score 1):

The thing is you need to escape the newline characters in your `foo` variable or pass its value to a proper place.

The same as writing any embeded shell script inside the makefile, you need to escape every new line. `$(foo)` will simply copy-paste a content from `foo` multi-line variable. Hence, for your given `foo` value, below recipe will raise a syntax error:

```
test1:
    echo '$(foo)'
```

Similar thing is for your `filter-out` example. I'm not sure why `filter` function gives no syntax error.

**1st solution.** As mentioned above, escaping a newline character is one of the solutions:

```
define foo
a\
b
endef

test1:
    echo '$(foo)'
```

The benefit is that you don't need to change your `all` recipe.

**2nd solution.** In most cases, you probably don't want to change/edit/parse your multi-line variable. Then you'll need to use a `shell` function that will directly invoke a shell command instead of pasting a script into the makefile contents and then parsing it. Our test recipe will look like this:

```
define foo
a
b
endef

test2:
    echo $(shell echo '$(foo)')
```

Note that output newlines are being converted to single spaces by [`shell` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html).